# How should I connect a cooktop to the house wiring?

Tags: wiring

How do I connect oven, cooktop to wall wire.
Oven wires: red,black,white,green

Cooktop- red,black,white,green

Wall wire- red, black,white,bare 
wire. 
Do I have to use bare wire in connection?

Comment: "*How do I connect oven, cooktop to wall wire*" What is wall wire ? is there an outlet on the wall ? Much more information is needed. Details Please.

Comment: No offense intended, but you may want to consider having an electrician do this for you, or contact your local building inspector to check it out after doing it yourself. Not getting this done correctly has the potential to cause your house to go up in flames. As a very beginner (based on the question you've asked) and the high amperage involved in a stove/cooktop, it may be worth a bit of expense to save a _lot_ of expense. At the minimum, consider finding a friend with some experience in home electrical work to show you and/or look over your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

Red to red , white to white , black to black and green to bare wire yes you do need to use the green / bare wire.

Since you said cooktop I would believe it is built in and you can use wire nuts listed for the wire sizes inside the box where the supply wires come from.

Just to explain  the green/ bare wire is your equipment ground , if a element shorts to the frame it the frame would be energized with 120v the green/bare wire dumps this to ground helping to trip the circuit breaker and eliminating the 120v on the metal.

You have a 240v range so why not 240v. US residential voltages are mostly split phase where the 240v is 2 each 120v legs that are out of phase so the maximum voltage to ground is 120v.

Comment: So I have to connect Green wires from cooktop and oven to Bare wire from wall( power wires)

Comment: Yes it really should be since you have it available. Bare and green or green with yellow Stripes are all equipment grounds.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: If you find an answer or comment helpful upvote it’s or accept it that’s how thanks work for DIY stack exchange.